# Displaying LinkedIn content with `iframe`

Tags: html, iframe, linkedin-api

I am making my website, and I want to put my LinkedIn profile in the Bio section.  However, when I use `iframe`, I get that LinkedIn refused to connect.  Is there a way to embed my LinkedIn profile in my website using HTML?  Thanks!

`<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/in/your-name"></iframe>` yields:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: See [this post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-linkedin-badge-your-website-brynne-tillman)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LinkedIn allows you to create a badge, and put that badge in your portfolio/website. So, in order to make a LinkedIn badge, follow these steps:

1. From your LinkedIn profile, click on `Contact Info` which is next to the number of your connections.
2. Then click on the pen at the top right corner to edit the `Contact Info`.
3. The first thing you'll notice is your LinkedIn profile link. Click on it.
4. A new page will be opened, you'll see a column at the right of the page, and at its end, you'll find a box entitled with `Public Profile badge` and a `Create a badge` button at the bottom. Click on that button.
5. Copy the `script` tag and paste it at the bottom of your HTML sheet.
6. Scroll down, you'll find 4 designs for your badge. Select the proper one and copy its code from the bottom of it and paste it where you want the badge to be shared.

**I know it's a long journey, but it's worth it.**

**NOTE:** The link to your LinkedIn profile will always open in the current tab, even if you add to the `a` tag the attributes `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"`. If you want the link to be opened in a new tab, put this line of code inside the `head` tag at the beginning of your HTML sheet `<base target="_blank" />`.

**Another IMPORTANT Note:** After putting the `base` tag inside your `head` tag, every single `a` tag inside that sheet will be opened in a new tab by default.

**HAPPY CODING AND GOOD LUCK**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27345510)

Comment: I thought it would be redundant to explain exactly the same steps. Thank you for letting me know this, I'm gonna edit my answer 

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I wanted.  I didn't know about the `<base>` tag in the header.  That's very helpful!  So, there's no way to display my entire profile?

Comment: No, LinkedIn doesn't give us the ability to embed our profile on other websites. However, Twitter supports that. You can embed your profile on any website you want with few simple steps.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers these days prevent this from occurring by expecting iframes to only frame pages from the same site. It's to prevent clickjacking. and it's controlled via the `X-Frame-Options` header. You should see a similar error on dev tools, if you press F12 you should see this error

[image]

```
*Clickjacking, also known as a “UI redress attack”, is when an attacker uses multiple transparent or opaque layers to trick a user into clicking on a button or link on another page when they were intending to click on the top level page.*
```

Your hosting provider may have a policy in place to prevent this from occuring, or if that's you, you will be able to amend this default value on your server.

You can disable this via Chrome for your development.